# why cant I more than two values from 3 different tables in one query

Tags: sql-server-2005, asp-classic

This is strange. In the news details page, I want to take a few different values from different tables with one query. However, for some strange reason, I only get two values back. So the outcome is like:

```
<Desc></Desc>
<Date/>
</row>
</rows>
```

If I disable fullname, then I get shortdesc but not others. Same things happens with others.

```
NewsID = Request.QueryString("NEWSID")  

SQL = "SELECT N.NewsID, N.MembersID, N.CategoriesID, N.ImagesID, N.NewsTitle, N.NewsShortDesc, N.NewsDesc, N.NewsActive, N.NewsDateEntered, C.CategoriesID, C.CategoriesName, M.MembersID, M.MembersFullName"

Set objViewNews = objConn.Execute(SQL)  

With Response
    .Write "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1254' ?>"
    .Write "<rows>"
End With

With Response
    .Write "<row id='"& objViewNews("NewsID") &"'>"
    .Write "<FullName>"& objViewNews("MembersFullName") &"</FullName>"
    .Write "<CategoryName>"& objViewNews("CategoriesName") &"</CategoryName>"
    .Write "</row>"
End With

With Response
    .Write "</rows>"
End With    

objViewNews.Close
Set objViewNews = Nothing
```

Comment: Yet another SQL injection vulnerability... that's the 3rd in one night, I'm starting to feel depressed.

Comment: @Aaronaught we should start a registry so we know which projects not to take over in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I'm assuming you are expecting a single row or only care about the first row?
2. Is MembersFullName nullable? Is NewsShortDesc nullable?
3. You should always check your inputs instead of concatenating them directly into the string. So you should use a function that verifies and checks that NewsID is of the type you expect and is properly escaped like so:

```
SQL = SQL & " Where N.NewsId = " & SqlString("int", newsId)
```

4.You might consider using the JOIN syntax like so:

(Presuming the input checking function)

```
    SQL = "SELECT N.NewsID, N.MembersID, N.CategoriesID, N.ImagesID, N.NewsTitle, N.NewsShortDesc, N.NewsDesc, N.NewsActive, N.NewsDateEntered, C.CategoriesID, C.CategoriesName, M.MembersID, M.MembersFullName"
    SQL = SQL & " FROM News N"
    SQL = SQL & "   Inner Join Categories C"
    SQL = SQL & "       On C.CategoriesID = N.CategoriesID"
    SQL = SQL & "   Inner Join Members M"
    SQL = SQL & "       On M.MembersID = N.MembersID"
    SQL = SQL & " Where N.NewsId = " & SqlString(VariantType.Integer
, NewsId)
    SQL = SQL & "   And N.NewsActive = 1"
```

(man the formatting can be quirky)

**EDIT** You should try wrapping all values in CDATA like so:

```
With Response
    .Write "<row id='"& objViewNews("NewsID") &"'>"
    .Write "<FullName><![CDATA["& objViewNews("MembersFullName") &"]]></FullName>"
    .Write "<CategoryName><![CDATA["& objViewNews("CategoriesName") &"]]></CategoryName>"
    .Write "<Title><![CDATA["& objViewNews("NewsTitle") &"]]></Title>"
    .Write "<ShortDesc><![CDATA["& objViewNews("NewsShortDesc") &"]]></ShortDesc>"
    .Write "<Desc><![CDATA["& objViewNews("NewsDesc") &"]]></Desc>"
    .Write "<Date>"& objViewNews("NewsDateEntered") &"</Date>"
    .Write "</row>"
End With
```

I did not wrap the date value in a CDATA although you might also consider doing so just to be sure.

Comment: even though all fields are nullable, neither fields are empty.

Comment: also I am pretty sure that NewsID is an integer so I dont think I need to check it with a function. I just used the codes you wrote, same result??

Comment: There one and only one row result from the query and if you Response.Write the all values directly, it outputs something for each value? 

You should always check values that go into any query even if you think you know it will be an integer in order to protect against SQL Injection (or even to let people know you are protecting against SQL Injection).

Comment: Yes it does. Try it: http://www.refinethetaste.com/FLPM/content/news/news.cs.asp?Process=ViewNews&NEWSID=2 change NEWSID value yourself to 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5.

Comment: BTW, you are checking *all* the values right not just ShortDesc and Fullname? You have tried Response.Write on all the values directly (i.e., not concatenated with anything) and they all output a value?

Comment: Actually, the output you showed me work correctly. CategoryName is clearly null in your query.

Comment: @zurna: you still need to check your inputs... I could use a query string like `...&NEWSID=1;DROP TABLE News;--` and drop your News table on you. You should maybe have a read of this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: I tried wrapping all fields in CDATA before. CategoriesName is definitely not null. It seems one query will not do it for me. I will divide it to 3 queries, I am sure it will work then. But thank you so much for trying it with me.

Comment: While you're at it, put that big ugly query in a stored procedure.